# 387: unexpected token at ruby json parse error

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON array in Ruby and getting the folloing error:

```
ERROR: 387: unexpected token at '{"A"=>"a1", "B"=>"01", "wc"=>"b1"}, {"A"=>"a2", "B"=>"0", "C"=>"b2"}]'
```

The JSON being parsed is:

```
{
    "node": [{
        "A": "a1",
        "B": "01",
        "C": "b1"
    }, {
        "A": "a2",
        "B": "0",
        "C": "b2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. This json is valid.

Comment: The hash in the first example looks different than the second. Why?

Comment: You sure you're parsing JSON?

Comment: I can't duplicate it using your example JSON, assuming you meant to having wrapping `'` to turn it into a String.

Comment: my code looks like below

Comment: my code looks like below
data_hash = JSON.parse("#{node["node"]}")
puts "#{data_hash.size}"